# ASP.net Application Architecture Suggestions?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, architecture

I need to create an Application Architecture for the .Net web application I am creating.

I am not too familiar with making a Application Architecture but the web app has the main .ASPX pages, and has VB.net codebehind files. Eventually we will implement a database into the web app.

From the logic in the codebehind we are going to be running remote scripts on Windows/Unix systems based on the options the user chooses in the main UI pages.

Any suggestions on how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you will be running scripts that could take long periods of time, I would set up WCF services to run the scripts asynchronously so that the calling web application won't get blocked.  Then, have the web application check another WCF service on the status of the ran script.  Most likely, you'll want the UI on the web application to be AJAX enabled so that the UI can refresh without needing a screen refresh.  Then just code the WCF services to run the scripts (permissions will be important to remember) and write a service to check the status of the script.

Comment: That is a very good idea. I am new to asp.net and .net programming but I just looked into WCF services and that may be a good idea. It seems that I would need to redo my project though...